# How calculate three phase kilowatt hour from time sampled data

Tags: matlab, math, arduino, signal-processing, discrete-mathematics

My problem is I want to calculate three phase power from time sampled data of current and voltages.

My questions:

1. How can I calculate the energy (unit kilowatt hour) from time sampled data? Are any equations available?
2. Is it needed to take the phase shift in account? (How can I calculate the phase shift? How do I link this to calculating the three phase power?)
3. Is some better platform is available for solving my question?

I get the instantaneous sample value (not continuous). (I have some sensors that gives the current and voltage - I convert this to digital for processing). Around 50 samples are got per second. (Is it to be zero when we some up all the power of three phase - due to phase shift of 120?) How can I calculate total three phase energy from these sampled values? I am processing my data in Arduino.

(I don't know this is the place to ask my question (if I can get a better help from some where else please suggest me).)

Comment: If you want to measure real (non reactive) power then you'll also need to calculate the power factor of your load (i.e. phase shift between voltage and current).

Comment: yes I have the power factor tooo

Comment: You might want to try asking on http://electronics.stackexchage.com as this is more of an electronics question than a programming question (which is why it's been closed here, presumably).

Answer (score 2):

Numerical calculus to the rescue.

---

If you have several samples of voltage and current, then you also have that many samples of momentary power: `P(t) = U(t) * I(t)`.

Now you have power and you have time, you can [**integrate**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) the power with respect to time. A simple numeric approach is the [trapezoidal rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Quadrature_rules_based_on_interpolating_functions). This question is tagged "Arduino" and I know C reasonably well so here's some pseudo-C that illustrates the technique:

```
int n_samples = 1000; // or however many samples you have
double integral = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < n_samples - 1; i++) {
    integral += (samples[i] + samples[i + 1]) / 2;
}

integral *= (t_max - t_min) / n;
```

Where `t_min` and `t_max` are the beginning and ending time of the sampling, respectively, `n_samples` is the number of samples you got, `samples` is an array (presumably of `double` or so) that contains the calculated momentary power values. `integral` will hold the result.

Comment: Thank you for your replay . My doubt is about three phase. How calculate this in case of three phase? Is it need to accommodate phase correction in three phase?

Comment: @Hacker How about **adding** the three results?

Comment: But I think phase shift must be encountered in case of three phase calculation.

Comment: @Hacker I don't precisely see what you want to calculate anyways. If it's total energy, then just add them together.

Comment: Do you have any idea about how we can calculate phase shift

Comment: I want to monitor three phase power. And I planed to make system which will display live kilowatt hour and total kilowatt hour of a indestry

Comment: What exactly you are measuring? Are you measuring U and I in all three phases separately?

Comment: yes yes I got sampled values of current and voltages of all phase. From these values I want to measure Kilowatt hour of three phase system. And I also I got the power factor from an another instoment

Comment: I doubt you are measuring faster than 100 times per second, so you have a "local time-average" of both U and I each phase (otherwise you have instantaneous U and I and will have instantaneous oscillating power too). Then calculate power for each phase as H2CO3 suggested and just sum them to get total power. See more here: http://ece.mst.edu/media/academic/ece/documents/classexp/ee209labs/Experiment_3_Power_Measurements.pdf

Comment: yes I got about 100 samples per sec.   @anandr Is it we need to consider phase shift/ Or any phase related correction is needed?

Comment: @anandr I get the instantaneous sample value (Not continues).(I have some sensors that gives the current and voltage - I convert this to digital for processing). Around 50 samples are got from 1sec.(Is it to be zero when we some up all the power of three phase - due to phase shift of 120) . How can I calculate total three phase kilo watt hour from these sampled value. I am processed my data in arduino.

Comment: AC power is not a simple product of voltage and current - loads have a resistive component and a reactive component, so the voltage and current have a relative phase shift (aka "power factor") which needs to be take into account.

Comment: @PaulR Isn't `P(t) = U(t) * I(t)` true *for momentary values?* OP claims to have samples of both.

Comment: @H2CO3: that's true for the vector sum of real + reactive power, but usually you want to measure real power, so you need the phase angle.

Comment: @PaulR OK, I see what you mean, we're talking about two different values. (According to you, is it sufficient to multiply the whole thing by `cos(phi)`, if any?)

Comment: @H2CO3: yes, but first you have to measure `phi`. And of course it gets even more complicated if the load is non-linear. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_factor for all the grisly details.

Comment: @PaulR Yes, I want an idea how to calculate the phase shift from the voltage and current samples. I am struggling to calculate the phase shift