# Best python method for calculating kw/h from data set

Tags: python

So I have a system reading the current from my power meter at set intervals (roughly every 30 seconds).

I want to then take these readings over an hour and calculate the kws used.

I have seen 2x methods on stakoverflow and wonder which is best.

Method 1 from here:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/225641

Method 2 from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16331700/5151115

Here is my testing code (this is after have converted current to power)
I am simulating a heater and readings of every 30 & 29 seconds.
The readings simply go 1350w -> 1400w -> 1350w.

```
# build sample data
time = 0
samples = [[0, 1350]]
for i in range(0, 61):
   samples.append([time+30, 1400])
   samples.append([time+59, 1350])
   time += 59

n_samples = len(samples)

# METHOD 1
total_ws = 0.0
for i in range(1, n_samples):
   dt = samples[i][0] - samples[i-1][0]
   average = (samples[i][1] + samples[i-1][1]) / 2
   total_ws += average * dt

print("Total w/s: %0.2f" % total_ws)
print("Total w/h: %0.2f" % (total_ws/samples[-1][0]))


# METHOD 2
total_ws = 0.0
for i in range(0, n_samples - 1):
   total_ws += (samples[i][1] + samples[i + 1][1]) / 2;

total_ws *= (samples[-1][0] - samples[0][0]) / n_samples;

print("Total w/s: %0.2f" % total_ws)
print("Total w/h: %0.2f" % (total_ws/samples[-1][0]))
```

Method 1
Total w/s: 4948625.00
Total w/h: 1375.00  = 1.375 Kw/h

Method 2:
Total w/s: 4908392.28
Total w/h: 1363.82 = 1.363 Kw/h

What method is more accurate / best?

The first method seems better to me as it gives me 1375.
This is the average of the 2x different readings (1350 & 1400).

Comment: python is pretty notoriously bad with floats and float division, look at pandas and numpy for better number support

Comment: Just thinking.  With a sample rate of once per 30 seconds, it seems to me that you are losing enough of the variability that it doesn't matter which method you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I'm more concerned about the best method out of the 2x above.
To me, the first method seems better as it gives 1375 which is the average of the 2x readings I am using in the test data (1350 & 1400).

I also might increase the reading interval. I'm using a battery powered ESP8266, so the longer it can sleep - the longer batter last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way can be used ONLY if dt between measurements is constant and I don’t like it since it is a source of mistake. The first way is much better for a varying dt and precision, but I prefer another. Look at this graph,
[image]

M1 stand to the first way.
"My" method is EQUAL.

```
# build sample data
time = 0
samples = [[0, 1350]]
for i in range(0, 200):
   samples.append([time+30, 1400])
   samples.append([time+60, 1350])
   time += 60

n_samples = len(samples)

# METHOD 1
total_ws = 0.0
total_t=0
for i in range(1, n_samples):
   dt = samples[i][0] - samples[i-1][0]
   average = (samples[i][1] + samples[i-1][1]) / 2
   total_ws += average * dt
   total_t+=dt
print("Total ws: %0.2f" % total_ws)
print("Total w: %0.2f" % (total_ws/total_t))

# METHOD 2
total_ws = 0.0
for i in range(0, n_samples - 1):
   total_ws += (samples[i][1] + samples[i + 1][1]) / 2;
total_ws *= (samples[-1][0] - samples[0][0]) / n_samples;
print("Total ws: %0.2f" % total_ws)
print("Total w: %0.2f" % (total_ws/samples[-1][0]))


# "My" METHOD 
total_ws = 0.0
total_t=0
for index in range(len(samples)):
    if index==0:dt=samples[index+1][0]/2.
    elif index==len(samples)-1:dt=(samples[index][0]-samples[index-1][0])/2.
    else:dt=(samples[index+1][0]-samples[index-1][0])/2.
    total_t+=dt
    total_ws+=samples[index][1] * dt
print("Total ws: %0.2f" % total_ws)
print("Total w: %0.2f" % (total_ws/total_t))
```

Pls pay attention for the modification i made in the methode 1

```
>>Total ws: 16500000.00
>>Total w: 1375.00
>>Total ws: 15950000.00
>>Total w: 1329.17
>>Total ws: 16500000.00
>>Total w: 1375.00
```

Comment: Great. So method2 is out.
I can't really see the difference between Method1 and "My" method.

Comment: yes method2 is out, they are the same in facte (but a bit different in CPU need). the surfaces areas are equal. But i prefer the other (just a personal reason : more graphical and more logique)

Comment: and in a extrem precision case, you can set an offset ratio for the time in this exemple it is set to 0.5 (mid time in betwin two points). if you know the derivative you can set the offset to get a better precision.(non linear interpolation)

Comment: Any ideas how I can "weight" in the interval the hour is calculated over?
eg. 1500w calculated over 3500 seconds should be considered higher than 1500w calculated over 3400 seconds.

Comment: I think a word is missing in your  sentence : i can't understand it

Comment: J=W*s so 5.25MJ for the First and 5.1MJ for the second, so more energie in the first place

Comment: But, if I only had 2x reading over a 1minute for an hour (some kind of fault stopped readings), and they were both 1500w, then it currently calculates that higher than something else with 120x readings at 1500w. I'd much prefer to use the more accurate hour as my "highest" hour as it's quite probable that the power dropped in the first hour

Comment: Maybe I should just throw away any hours with less than 100 readings.

Comment: I forgot to mention. My whole goal is to work out the hour of most used power. My power company gives me a free hour of power each day that can be changed even after the hour as long as changed before midnight. So, goal is at 11:55pm - to calculate the power usage of each hour of the current day and then set my power hour to the highest

Comment: OK, you can try to set a centered local mean of an hour interval then you can consider his maximum to be 30 min past the start of the  hour  of higher consumption, anyway try to get consistante dt  and try to set all power consumption to were you usualy burn the more

Comment: What about if I do. total_seconds / 3600 which gives me an "accuracy" percentage. eg. 3500 / 3600 = 0.972.  or 60 / 3600 = 0.0167. Then I multiple the total_ws by this.  0.972 * 1500 = 1458.  0.0167 * 1500 = 26.4. I then rank them based on this number?

Comment: Wtf ? Why are you so mutch focused on bad mesurments ? Bad mesurment  never apend and in case they do, simply make the software ask for human  assistance. How are you going to mesure and give the instant power to the software ? that seam  to be the real  stuff in this project, for me as soon as you get it less than 30 python lines will make  the deal

Comment: It was more just a worst case if the reader stopped reading. I will just ignore any hours without at least 100x readings. I'm not actually displaying the hourly usage. I just need to work out the highest hour of the day and the end of day (automatically) and update my power company's free hour :)

Answer (score 0):

t2-t1 = 1 hour
S1 is the area under the blue curve from t1 to t2 (aka integrale).
E1 (Joules) = S1(w)/3600(s), so it represent the local total power consumption of the next houre.
You then simply need to pick the max E1 of the day to get the most power consuming hour, in this case h=7 to 7+1 !
[image]